# Which user settings should I add to version control if I am the only person using the repo?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, resharper, gitignore

I have a very similar gitignore to: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Given that I am the only one that will use the repo and I want to have the same settings on both my computers (prefs, shortcuts, which projects should be loaded and those that should not be loaded when i open the sln, etc); which ones should I comment out? I also use resharper on both computers.

I assume that I should for sure look closely into these lines:

```
# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates
*.vcxproj.filters

# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user
```

Should I also look at NUGET package lines?

Haribol.

Answer (score 0):

The settings you're talking about are stored in very different locations. Shortcuts, for one, are stored in a vssettings file in your home folder. It is not shared across repositories. However, there is an option for  [synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135229.aspx).

ReSharper is able to share settings this way. You can read more about it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html). You may also want to look at the Dropbox plugin.